# VSTS CI - how to trigger a build for single project

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am working with Visual Studio Team Services Build definition triggers. I am trying to set a Continuous Integration and Delivery for **one** project on my branch (but not the entire branch with many projects). This will help me build and release individual microservice (when the contract did not change...).

I could not find the answer here or on in the official docs:
[Build definition triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers?view=vsts)

I did try to play with the Path filters but it has proven not to be a robust way. I might got it wrong...

[image]

Any guidance will be appreciated. Tnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger CI build only when changes made on `project3`, you can only specify the path filter to the project directory.

Such as if the file structure in your repo as below:

```
Root repo
    |___ project1
            |___ ...
    |___ project2
            |___ ...
    |___ project3
            |___ ...
    |___ project.sln
    |___...
```

Then you can specify the path filter as below:

[image]

And to upload the build artifacts only about `project3` for Continuous Deployment, you can copy related files from `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\project3` to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, and then upload build artifacts from `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested it again and it works. First time, before even posting this Q, I remember trying this approach and checkins triggered all the CI build. Must have been too tired .... Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to specify the CI option and enable it.
Enabling the "Batch changes while a build is in progress" is optional.

[image]

Add the branches you want to "Branch filters".

Then add the "Include" and the list of paths that you want to trigger the build.

Since you added to exclude all in your configurations (as in your question), the build cannot include the other directory.

You also don't need to specify the "*" in the path.

Comment: thanks. So, If I have projects named 1, 2, 3 ... N. and I would like to CI only say project 3. How the path filtres should look like?

Comment: You have to have one build for each project and then specify the directories used for the build, so that it is started only when the specific directories are changed

Comment: Yes that is the setting I have. I appreciate your time. Thanks.